# I'm little bit confused that whether automatic memory allocation takes place during run time or compile time

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, static-memory-allocation

I know that the memory is allocated at compile time to auto variables like `int a;` and are stored in stack but in case of a variable array whose input is taken from the user, for eg

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
 int n;
 printf("enter the size of array");
 scanf("%d",&n);
 int a[n];
 .......
}
```

the memory is allocated at run time. So my question is, is the automatic allocation is case dependent or not. THANKS

Comment: Seems you could reason this out yourself. If the value of `n` isn't known at compile time, but will be determined at run time based on user input, then the memory can't possibly be allocated at compile time, right? Because the value of `n` isn't known at compile time?

Comment: All memory is allocated at run-time and only at run-time. It is not possible to "allocate" anything at compile-time. All you can do at compile-time is "draw" the future memory *layout* in terms of absolute or relative offsets. This memory layout is materialized (allocated) at run-time.

Comment: @AnT so if all the allocation takes place during runtime, so is the static memory allocation also takes place during runtime because it is said that it takes place during compile time.

Comment: @KenWhite that's what my question is, is it case dependent or not?

Comment: @Coderandhacker What do you think the word “allocation” means? The way you’re using it doesn’t make sense with its standard meaning, which is where a *running* process gets a certain region of memory to store data. It is impossible for that to happen at compile time; the earliest it can happen is at program load time, right before your program’s code starts executing.

Comment: @Coderandhacker: "Allocation" is a rather ambiguous term. It can mean several different things. E.g. planning the future memory layout is "allocation". Requesting actual memory block from the environment is also "allocation". The former happens at compile-time, the latter - at run time. Your question touches/mixes/confuses both concepts, which is probably the reason for the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, it is unclear where "a" is defined. So, I'll take a stab at answering this by making assumptions on that.

1. If the array is declared as a global array, it resides in the bss segment, and memory is allocated as the segments are loaded into memory.
2. If the array is on the stack, and the size of the array is known at compile-time, the stack pointer is moved to allocate space for the array. You can see this if you disassemble the code.
3. If the array is on the stack, but space is allocated based on an argument to the function you have a VLA(variable length array). These are commonly converted to "alloca" calls by the compiler. In this case the stack pointer is just moved to allocated "n" bytes on the stack.
4. If the array is on the heap, the allocations are performed by the heap allocator in use.

Comment: please see code properly, the a is defined just below the scanf statement

Comment: @Coderandhacker That’s option 3.

Comment: Why is it unclear where `a` is defined? It's clearly an automatic VLA.

Comment: It is unclear where `a` is defined because the OP says `int a;` and then in the code they have `int a[n];`. These two declarations mean very different things. Please read the code indeed.

Answer (score 1):

The *code* that handles the automatic allocation is created at compile-time. The actual allocation takes place in run-time. You'll have machine code such as "push variable on stack" or "put variable in register", but this code is of course doing nothing until the program is executed. All stack allocations are done in run-time. They may or may not be of a deterministic nature.

In the case of a VLA, the instruction "move stack pointer n steps" is created at compile time, but the variable `n` is set in run-time and the stack pointer is then moved accordingly, to allocate memory.

The only kind of allocation that takes place at compile-time is allocation of objects with static storage duration - meaning allocation of file scope variables and `static` variables. Room for these are reserved in the data segments usually named `.data` and `.bss` on most systems.

Examples can be found [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/237759/6102).